# Arkit - 3d Model real size in swift

Tags: swift, size, scale, arkit

I am exporting 3d model with real world dimensions in 3dsMax. When I use it arkit project, it looks so big. For this reason, I scaled it 1/1000 in arkit project swift. Is there any other way. Can I scale 1/1000 the scene directly

Answer (score 0):

You can scale down by this way :

var modelNode: SCNNode!

......

modelNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001) //as per requirement (0.5,0.5,0.5)

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelNode)